# Wordpress preventing subscribers from insert/delete/update content with Rest API

Tags: php, wordpress, rest, api

I am working on a website which uses WP. I created a registration form which adds user with "subscriber" role to the database.

I want to disallow the access to the Back office (wp-admin) to the 'subscribers'. 
I put this :

```
if ( is_user_logged_in() && is_admin() && current_user_can( 'subscriber' ) ) {
      wp_redirect( home_url() );
      exit;
}
```

Until here, everything is good.

I saw we have the possibility to insert/delete/update... posts with the WP Rest API.

I was wondering if a user who has a 'subscriber' role can insert POST via the Rest API ? Knowing that as mentionned on the codex : a Subscriber is somebody who can only manage their profile. He can not publish and manage posts.

Thank you

Comment: No, by default they don't have permissions for that. You either need to grant them contributor or create your own role with permissions that you need.

Comment: So if a person subscribes to my website and sends a POST/PUT/DELETE request to the Rest API, nothing will happen ?

Comment: To add to what @IgorYavych said, you can add a new role or change permissions of existing roles using the [User Role Editor](https://wordpress.org/plugins/user-role-editor/) plugin - you can easily grant the permissions your subscribers through checkboxes. However its not advisable to change the default user permissions - you'd be better creating your own new role based on the Subscriber (easily done using the plugin) and grant them the additional permissions.

Comment: I do not want to change the role, I want to know if a user who has a subscriber role can send request to the Rest API. For example an administrator can send request (of course he has to authentificate)

Comment: If you are only asking if it works or not, then why not try it and see? "Does this happen"-type questions are off topic. Questions should have a *clear problem statement* and it is expected that you have researched your issue and made a [good attempt to figure it out for yourself](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users#answer-261593) . See [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), specifically *"Explain [...] any difficulties that have **prevented you from solving it yourself**."*